# Update database when file is added

Tags: database, file

Having a server(ish) I want a way to keep track of the files I have in some folders with a web-interface. I have done most of the programming already, by basically parsing through the folders each load ( not the most optimized way but it has had it advantages as well ). But now the reasons of keeping the files in a database has become overwhelming.

So - How do I do this in the best way possible.
The way I had thought was to have a script running and add a database entry whenever a file was added to a folder I was listening to. 
Is there an easy way to accomplish this? Or would you solve this problem in a completely different matter?

edit:
right sorry.
Operating system is a bit difficult - not really. But at the moment it's written on an os x machine but eventually it's going up on an linux so I'll absolutely have a look at inotify. Do you know any others like it for say os x.

Comment: What operating system are you using? That will dictate some of the solutions. For example, on Linux, you could make use of inotify.

Comment: Also, which flavour of database?  Some databases have scheduling APIs and file handling APIs.  So you might have the option to pull files from within the database as well as pushing them from the OS.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a Windows Service (which runs all the time) that contains a FileWatcher component (I think it's called this). When a new file is detected, make a call to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Use [incron](http://incron.aiken.cz/) to run a script to update the database whenever a file is added or removed.

Answer (score 0):

You mention using OS X - you can use the [File System Events](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) library.

On linux, you'd use inotify (perhaps using a wrapper such as incron, which another poster mentioned).